# How to get the (x, y)-coordinates relative to an element's origin in d3 VERSION 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to get the mouse coordinates relative to an element's origin, instead of to the origin of the page.

If I understood correctly, this could be done using d3.mouse(this) in version 3 of d3, e.g.:

```
d3.select('svg').on('click', () => {
    let coor = d3.mouse(this)
    console.log(coor[0])
}
```

However, when I try this in version 4, I get a 't.getBoundingClientRect is not a function'- Error.

I know that you can get the (x,y) coordinates relative to the page's origin using

```
d3.event.clientX or d3.event.clientY
```

But I couldn't find how to get values without doing all kinds of lengthy adjustments. Is there a simple way of doing this using d3 version 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as a listener callback, `this` will refer to the global object, i.e. most likely to `window`, which does not feature a method `.getBoundingClientRect()`, hence the error. This has nothing to do with D3 and is equally applicable to all its versions. There are two ways around this:

#### 1. Use a standard function expression.

```
    d3.select('svg').on('click', function() {
      let coor = d3.mouse(this);
      console.log(coor[0]);
    });
```

#### 2. Get the current element by means of the function parameters.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on):

> the specified *listener* will be evaluated for the element, being passed the current datum (*d*), the current index (*i*), and the current group (*nodes*)

To get the *current element*, which in an arrow function is not referred to as `this`, you can reference it as `nodes[i]` instead. Your statement then becomes:

```
    d3.select('svg').on('click', (d, i, nodes) => {
      let coor = d3.mouse(nodes[i]);
      console.log(coor[0]);
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, that seems to do the trick. So it wasn't a d3 related or version related problem after all... Well, the more you know.